# Getting a Visual Studio 2022 clang linking error on libcpmt about some PDB issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2022

I have been having some linking errors when trying to use Clang with Visual Studio 2022 on my project.

I am able to use Clang under VS2019 and I know that the VS2022 Clang toolchain was properly installed since I can create and compile a new 'console project' using them. I tried reverting most project settings, making them match the blank 'console project' but to not avail.

Does anyone have an idea of what setting could be causing this?

Thank you.

**Environment**

- Windows 10 (10.0.19041.0)
- Visual Studio community 2022 (64bits) 17.2.4 with Clang 13.0.1
- Visual Studio community 2019 (also installed) with Clang 12.0.0

**Repro**

- Download **NetImgui** (Dev branch) at **https://github.com/sammyfreg/netImgui/tree/dev**
- Generate solution with **GenerateProjects.bat** (it uses Ubisoft sharpmake to create projects)
- Open **_Projects\vs2022_netImgui_All.sln** with VS2022 and Clang toolchain installed
- Compile **Samples\SampleBasic** with **Clang_Debug** and **x64** build target
- Linking error occurs

**Linking Errors**

```
3>------ Build started: Project: SampleBasic, Configuration: Clang_Debug x64 ------
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_Load_barrier` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\xtime.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1291 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1338 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_Container_proxy::_Container_proxy` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1335 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12A7 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::bad_array_new_length::bad_array_new_length` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12B5 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::bad_array_new_length::bad_array_new_length` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12AA which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::error_code::error_code` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x136B which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::error_condition::error_condition` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x136F which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::runtime_error::runtime_error` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1358 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_System_error::~_System_error` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x137D which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12A9 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::error_category::~error_category` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1369 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_System_error::`scalar deleting destructor'` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x137C which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::bad_alloc::`scalar deleting destructor'` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12A8 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::exception::`scalar deleting destructor'` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x12A4 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_Adjust_manually_vector_aligned` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1334 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_System_error::_Makestr` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1379 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all_locked_v3` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1336 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::_Container_base12::_Swap_proxy_and_iterators_locked` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x1337 which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : procedure symbol record for `std::error_code::category` in D:\a\_work\1\s\Intermediate\vctools\libcpmt.nativeproj_658832323\objd\amd64\thread0.obj refers to PDB item index 0x136D which is not a valid function ID record
3>lld-link : error : too many errors emitted, stopping now (use /errorlimit:0 to see all errors)
3>Done building project "SampleBasic.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing, I was able to narrow it down to using

- Runtime Library: Multi-Threaded [Debug]

Instead of

- Runtime Library: Multi-Threaded [Debug] DLL

I will inquire with Microsoft to know if this is a SDK issue.

Microsoft anwser : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/930347/visual-studio-2022-llvm-linking-warning.html#answer-932833